# In which order do I use OR in this probability question?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm given the question:

> A dice is rolled $15$ times. What is the probability that either a $1$ or $6$ is scored exactly **eight times**?

Now I know that the probability $1$ is scored exactly $8$ times is...

$Let \space P({X_n}=m)= Probability \space n \space is \space scored \space m \space times$

$P({X_1}=8)={15\choose 8} ({1\over 6})^8 ({5\over 6})^7$

And since it's a fair dice, likewise...

$P({X_6}=8)={15\choose 8} ({1\over 6})^8 ({5\over 6})^7$

Now about the "either $1$ or $6$" part, do I do that FIRST as in...

$P({X_1} \cup {X_6}) = {2\over 6}$

Then do...

$ {15\choose 8} ({2\over 6})^8 ({4\over 6})^7 $

OR...

Is it meant to be done as the final step like so...

$P( P({X_1}=8) \cup P({X_6}=8))$

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  One cannot tell from that wording alone whether it asks for the probability that (a) either the number of $1$'s is $8$, or the number of $6$'s is $8$; or (b) the number of $1$'s plus the number of $6$'s is $8$.

Comment: @Brian Tung - Tell me about it. This is exactly how the question is worded. The wording of problems always throws me off things that I often don't even find difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inclusion-exclusion,
\begin{align*}
P(X_1=8\cup X_6=8) &= P(X_1 = 8)+P(X_6 = 8)-P(X_1 = 8, X_6 = 8)\\
& = \binom{15}{8}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^8\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^7+\binom{15}{8}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^8\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^7+0\\
&= 2\binom{15}{8}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^8\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^7
\end{align*}
where $P(X_1 = 8, X_6 = 8)=0$ since you can't roll 8 ones and 8 sixes since you only roll 15 times.

---

> A dice is rolled $15$ times. What is the probability that either a $1$ or $6$ is scored exactly **eight times**?

If the interpretation is that on each roll, you treat a one and a six a success (you are interested in rolling a one or a six), then  let
$$Y_i = \{\text{Roll a six or a one on roll $i$}\}.$$
Then let $S = Y_1+\dotsc+Y_{15}$ which follows $\text{Bin}(15, p = 2/6)$ and so
$$P(S = 8) = \binom{15}{8}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^8\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^7.$$

Answer (score 1):

To answer Arthur's interpretation of probablyme's answer, note that the probability of rolling either a $1$ or a $6$ on a given roll is $1/3$, so the probability of obtaining either a $1$ or a $6$ on exactly $8$ of the $15$ rolls is

$$
P = \binom{15}{8}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^8 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7
$$

My advice is to determine, somehow, which interpretation of the question is intended, and answer accordingly.  Failing that, specify both interpretations and answer both.

Answer (score 1):

The question *is* a little ambiguous.   Your calculations for the possible  interpretations are correct.   However, your expressions of *what* you are calculating is a little off.

Let $X_n$ be the count of occurrences of result $n$ in $15$ rolls of a fair die.   Then we are required to find one of these probabilities:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1=8\cup X_6=8) \; = \;& 2\;\dbinom{15}{8}\dfrac{5^7}{6^{15}} & \textsf{either obtain 1, or 6, exactly eight times }
\\[2ex] \mathsf P(X_1+X_6=8) \; = \; & \dbinom{15}{8}\dfrac{2^8\,4^7}{6^{15}} & \textsf{obtain, either 1 or 6, exactly eight times}\end{align}$$